# Question on a polynomial $f(x)$ with rational coefficients

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x)= (x-\alpha)^ng(x)$, then $f(\alpha)= f'(\alpha)= f''(\alpha)=...= f^{(n-1)}(\alpha)= 0$, where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials.
>
> For a polynomial $f(x)$ with rational coefficients, answer the
>   following question:
>
> If $f(x) $ is of degree $3$ and touches x axis, then how many roots of
>   $f(x)$ are rational?

I tried to use rational root theorem. But I am not able to obtain a definite answer from this.

Comment: What does "touches" mean?

Comment: @EricWofsey X axis is tangent at a point

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d$ (with $a \ne 0$),  then 
$$ 3 f(x) - \left(x + \frac{b}{3a}\right) f'(x) = \frac{(6ac - 2 b^2) x + (9ad - bc)}{3a}$$
The case where $3 f(x) - (x+b/(3a)) f'(x) \equiv 0$ should be dealt with separately.  Otherwise, if $f$ and $f'$ have a common root it is $ (bc-9ad)/(6ac-2b^2)$, and thus is rational if $a,b,c,d$ are rational.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Try $f(x) = (x-r)^3$.